# Why do I get a bind error in my socket programs? Is it because I am not closing the sockets correctly?

Tags: sockets, posix

I am writing simple server and client programs for socket communication. Sometimes, I get a bind error in my server program and sometimes it works as expected.

Shown below is my code for the server

```
int Socket;
struct sockaddr_in Server;

Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(Socket == -1){
    printf("Socket error\n");
}

Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
Server.sin_port = htons(50000);

if(connect(Socket, (struct sockaddr *)&Server, sizeof(Server)) < 0){
    printf("Connection Error\n");       
    return 1;
}

char Buf[100];
while(1){
    memset(Buf, '\0', sizeof(Buf)); 
    if(recv(Socket, &Buf, 100, 0) < 0){
        printf("Error to receive\n");
        close(Socket);
        return 1;

    }

    if(!strncmp(Buf, "quit\n", 5))
        break;


}
close(Socket);

return 0;
```

And my server code:

```
int Socket;
struct sockaddr_in server_address, myClient;

Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(Socket == -1){
    printf("Socket Erro\n");
    return 1;
}

memset(&server_address, '0', sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(50000);


if(bind(Socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0){

    printf("bind error\n");
    return 1;
}

listen(Socket, 10); 
int nSocket;

nSocket = accept(Socket, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

if(nSocket < 0){
    perror("Accept Failed");
    return 1;

}

char Buf[100];
while(1){
    memset(Buf, '\0', sizeof(Buf));
    fgets(&Buf[0], 100, stdin); 

    int temp = strchr(Buf, '\n') - Buf;
    write(nSocket, Buf, temp+1);        

    if(!strcmp(Buf, "quit\n"))
        break;

}
close(Socket);

return 0;
```

Sometimes when I run the server, I get a bind error and other times not. It usually happens when I quit the server and start it again. Could it be because I am not closing the sockets correctly? Could it be because I am closing the socket from both sides?

Comment: @EJP There is a terminating mechanism - if you type in "quit". Thank you, I addressed the issues that you pointed out, but it still doesn't answer my question about the bind error. I never get a receive or an accept error

Comment: Flagged EJP's comment to be removed. There is no place here for condescending comments. Especially when the person clearly did not even review your whole code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the mistake. The problem was that I tried to run the server again directly after I quit it. This caused problems with binding the socket again, since the OS makes it unavailable for a short period of time after the socket has been closed.

After:

```
Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

I added the following lines to the server program after the

```
int enable = 1;
if (setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
```

I also fixed many mistakes regarding error handling as pointed out by @EJP, that were not directly causing my problem.

Comment: thank you for pointing out that the OS keeps the socket busy for a brief time. This totally saved my day. Adding a sleep statement was all it took to fix an error i had been staring at for an hour.